# Complex variable (variable name change with others variable) possible?

Tags: java

I would like to use a way for use variable to change the name of an other variable...
Because an example is always appropriate :

```
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
  ${a.$i} = "value";
}   

echo "$a1, $a2, $a3, $a4, $a5";
//Output is value, value, value, value, value
?>
```

For me, I got 5 steps, for each step, I have a description like step1_desc, can I do something like step{step}_desc in java ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not possible in Java.  You'll need to use a data structure such as an array or collection.

Comment: Really not possible ? okey thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use array, or `Map` to do this,

```
String arr[] = new String[3];
arr[0]="value1";
arr[1]="value2";
arr[2]="value3";
```

or

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("anyName", "anyValue");
//access it now
map.get("anyName");
```

Comment: I'm on android, to get a String I need to use getString(R.string.step1_desc), I can't use an array, I can just try to modify my variable with an other variable. Or an other way without use if/else/switch... but I only see my way to not be repetitive.